# How should I relate to each position in drop-down-list in React using functional components and states

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, state, react-hooks

I have react functional component - Shop. I add in return section drop down list using select and options.My problem is about if statement. I don't know what should I type in If (). Now if I select option with id 'a' or option with id 'b' the results is the same and I don't know why. It doesn't see that I change selection in drop down list and always returns filters relate to first If() statement with id'a'. Even if I choose option in my drop down list with id'b' it always use returt statement relate to if with id'a'. I think that this only check if in drop down list there is a possibility to select option with such Id but I would like to check if it is actually selected an if yes return something. Thank you in advance for help.

Please see part of code below.

```
const Shop: React.FC<ShopProps> = (props: ShopProps) => { 
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState(props.selectedShop.address);

const filterShopBy = (item: any, event: any) => {
if (onChange=()=>setSelectedOption(document.getElementById('a'))){
return 'some code1 which I use to filter data';
} 
else if (onChange=()=>setSelectedOption(document.getElementById('b'))){
return 'some code2 which I use to filter data'; }
}

return (
<div className="filters">
<select id='list' className='droplist' value={selectedOption} onChange={(e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)} > 
<option id='a' value={props.selectedShop.address} onClick={() => setSelectedOption(props.selectedShop.address)}>Shop address</option>
<option id='b' value={props.selectedShop.name} onClick={() => setSelectedOption(props.selectedShop.name)}>Shop name</option>
</select>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues here. I think main the problem resides in your if evaluation. Cuz it will always enter the first if and return. My advice is to only use the state and evaluate the state! And avoid those *ids* because you have simpler ways to solve the problem. Let me know if this following code helps you out:

```
const Shop = props => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState("B");

  // In my opinion it's way simpler to work with state
  if (selectedOption === "A") {
    //Do something here
  } else if (selectedOption === "B") {
    //Do something here
  }

  return (
    <div className="filters">
      <select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={evt => setSelectedOption(evt.target.value)} // You just need one "onChange"
      >
        <option value="A" id={1}>
          A
        </option>
        <option value="B" id={2}>
          B
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

Comment: No problem, anytime! :)